# Slow rotation down in Unity Animator

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have a simple rotation animation that spins an object on its axis. At the moment its spinning too quick and I want to slow it down, I've tried increasing the samples?? But I don't know that much about animation so I might be well off. How do I slow an animation down? It only has two keys.

Comment: Hello,  Unfortunately, I don't see the field  "SPEED" on the animation editor, which was created by some other developers.  Is it "SPEED only available on some older versions of Unity ? Does Unity automatically create that field "SPEED" ? Or does that developer have to explicitly create that field "SPEED" ? (Thanks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, open the state machine associated with this animator by double-clicking on the controller field of your object.

[image]

Then select the animation you would want to slow down in the state machine. Then in Inspector panel there is a `speed` field. You can just decrease its value to slow the animation down.

[image]

Comment: Hello,  Unfortunately, I don't see the field  "SPEED" on the animation editor, which was created by some other developers.  Is it "SPEED only available on some older versions of Unity ? Does Unity automatically create that field "SPEED" ? Or does that developer have to explicitly create that field "SPEED" ? (Thanks)